# Creating .msi file for Excel Addin with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, installation, vsto

maybe someone can help me with the following problem.

I create a new Excel Ribbon with Visual Studio 2017. When I run the solution out of Visual Studio everything works fine. Excel is open and the Ribbon and buttons give no exception. So far so good.

Now I need to create a .msi file, so that the solution can be roll out to the customer. Therefore I add the Visual Studio Installer projects to my VS and create a setup project. This is also working fine for, say a normal HalloWorld.exe on the Console. But when I do it for the Excel Addin it does not work. I get the .msi file, I can install it, but I never see it in Excel. I can also not see the Addin in Excel on File->Options->Addins->Com-Add-Ins.

Did anybody give me a clue what is needed, what need to be add or to change to install the Excel Addin to other users?

Best Regards,

Sebastian

Comment: There is a lot that could be going wrong. You need to try publishing the Add-In without the *.msi first, and then determine why that doesn't work (because it probably won't).

Comment: Doing anything other than a click-once deployment for a VSTO add-on is brutal.  The instructions are long, confusing and very easy to mess up.  I have only done it once successfully, and I've never been able to repeat it with any other add-ons.  If at all possible, use click-once, which is a breeze by comparison.

Comment: Yes, it works well with ClickOnce. But with Click Once, I have multiple files. Our SCCM Administror says, we need only one msi file to publish the solution to all our users. So, I try to publis first with ClickOnce and then creating the msi with the installer. But that also does not work :-(

Comment: Then you need to determine where it is failing. Try [log alerts](http://www.macroview.com.au/support/KnowledgeBase/Pages/20110084.aspx) or the [event log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442816.aspx). The certificate you use to sign it must also be [trusted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772086.aspx).

Comment: I think I found a good solution on the following Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer#ConfigureRegisitry    To say it short. It was important to add the registry entries, the manifest and the .vsto file to the solution.